# Is there an event for any kind of interaction (click, mousedown, keydown etc)

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, events

I'm looking for an event which combines all other events which fall under the user-page interactions category. This would include **click, mousedown, mouseup, keydown, keyup** and so on. In short, an *"interaction"*  would be any event after which the script will be allowed to play audio, or `writeText()` to the `clipboard`.

I'm looking something like this...

```
window.addEventListener("interaction", async () => {
    await navigator.clipboard.writeText("Copied some text");
}, { once: true });
```

**... As opposed to looping through `["click, "keyup"...]` and creating a separate event listener for each.**

Comment: Not just "paste" or "input" ?

Comment: No such single master event exists. What is your use case and what higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Having an array like the one you suggested may not be such a bad idea.